# How do you use deck.gl to load a laz file and place it over a mapbox map in the correct location from laz data?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl

I have read the example on deck.gl but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

My code

```
import './style.css'
import {load} from '@loaders.gl/core';
import {LASLoader} from '@loaders.gl/las';
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'
import {MapboxLayer} from '@deck.gl/mapbox';
import {PointCloudLayer} from '@deck.gl/layers';
import {COORDINATE_SYSTEM} from '@deck.gl/core';
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
import '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css';
let url = "poleta.laz"
const data = await load(url, LASLoader);
console.log(data)
let pointCloudLayer = new MapboxLayer(
    {
        id: 'deckgl-PointCloudLayer',
        type: PointCloudLayer,
        loaders: [LASLoader],
        coordinateSystem: COORDINATE_SYSTEM.CARTESIAN,
        //or load directly
        //  data: 'poleta.laz'
        data: data,
        getNormal: [0, 1, 0],
        getColor: [255, 255, 255],
        opacity: 0.5,
        pointSize: 0.5
    }
);
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.D_ngzR7j4vU1CILtpNLg4Q';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container ID
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12', // style URL
    center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 9, // starting zoom
});
map.addControl(
    new MapboxGeocoder({
        accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
        mapboxgl: mapboxgl
    })
);

map.on('load', function() {
    map.addLayer(pointCloudLayer)
});
```

The laz file is from opentopograhy and is from Poleta Folds, California

1. Will deck.gl figure out the long, lat and place the point cloud in the correct location?  Or do I need to manually set the coordinateOrigin?
2. How do I get the coordinateOrigin lng, lat from the laz file?

3)Do I need to lookup the EPSG and use that in a deck.gl parameter?

From the laz info I looked up the EPSG -- EPSG:32611 WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N

I have run the program las2las to get the information from the laz file, and get an ouptut of

```
lasinfo (230821) report for 'poleta.laz'
reporting all LAS header entries:
  file signature:             'LASF'
  file source ID:             0
  global_encoding:            0
  project ID GUID data 1-4:   00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
  version major.minor:        1.2
  system identifier:          'LAStools (c) by rapidlasso GmbH'
  generating software:        'lastile (140403) unlicensed'
  file creation day/year:     66/2014
  header size:                227
  offset to point data:       1083
  number var. length records: 3
  point data format:          1
  point data record length:   28
  number of point records:    781878
  number of points by return: 781878 0 0 0 0
  scale factor x y z:         0.00025 0.00025 0.00025
  offset x y z:               399307 4097856 2474
  min x y z:                  399990.00450 4096990.00150 1766.39525
  max x y z:                  401009.99950 4098009.99375 2634.98200
variable length header record 1 of 3:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34735
  length after header  64
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoKeyDirectoryTag'
    GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 7
      key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeProjected
      key 1025 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTRasterTypeGeoKey: RasterPixelIsArea
      key 1026 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 22 value_offset 0 - GTCitationGeoKey: WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N
      key 2049 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 7 value_offset 22 - GeogCitationGeoKey: WGS 84
      key 2054 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree
      key 3072 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 32611 - ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey: WGS 84 / UTM 11N
      key 3076 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter
variable length header record 2 of 3:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'LASF_Projection'
  record ID            34737
  length after header  30
  description          'GeoTIFF GeoAsciiParamsTag'
    GeoAsciiParamsTag (number of characters 30)
      WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N|WGS 84|
variable length header record 3 of 3:
  reserved             43707
  user ID              'liblas'
  record ID            2112
  length after header  600
  description          'OGR variant of OpenGIS WKT SRS'
LASzip compression (version 2.2r0 c2 50000): POINT10 2 GPSTIME11 2
LAStiling (idx 852, lvl 6, sub 0, bbox 370000 4081000 434000 4145000, buffer) (size 1000 x 1000, buffer 9.9995)
reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ...
  X             2732018    6811998
  Y            -3463994     615975
  Z            -2830419     643928
  intensity        1541      13107
  return_number       1          1
  number_of_returns   1          1
  edge_of_flight_line 0          1
  scan_direction_flag 1          1
  classification      0          0
  scan_angle_rank   -40         37
  user_data           0          0
  point_source_ID     1          1
  gps_time 71047.074070 71668.754190
number of first returns:        781878
number of intermediate returns: 0
number of last returns:         781878
number of single returns:       781878
overview over number of returns of given pulse: 781878 0 0 0 0 0 0
histogram of classification of points:
          781878  never classified (0)
```